# Symfony Form - clear session variable only when I enter the form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, session, session-variables

I want to clear session variable only when I enter my symfony form first time. In this example session is delete even when form is not valid - how can I change this?

```
public function dodajNewAction(Request $request, Pacjent $pacjent)
{
    unset($_SESSION['test']);

    $wykbad = new Wykbadpoz($pacjent);
    $wykbad->setRok(date('Y'));
    $wykbad->setMiesiac(date('n')); //miesiac bez zera wiodacego

    $form = $this->createForm('nfz_wykbadpoz_new', $wykbad);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    return [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Symfony project you should **never** use superglobals like `$_SESSION` (`$_GET`, `$_POST`, ...). You must use the `Request` object.

Like this:

```
public function dodajNewAction(Request $request, Pacjent $pacjent)
{
    $wykbad = new Wykbadpoz($pacjent);
    $wykbad->setRok(date('Y'));
    $wykbad->setMiesiac(date('n')); //miesiac bez zera wiodacego

    $form = $this->createForm('nfz_wykbadpoz_new', $wykbad);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $session = $request->getSession();
    if ($form->isValid() && $session->has('test')) {
        $session->remove('test');
    }

    return [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ];
}
```